# Detect Tap on sides of the phone (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, accelerometer

I would like to know how to detect tapping (or slight jerk) on any side of the phone. 
I mean to say that, I want to perfom a task, when the phone is tapped on the top, and something else when it is tapped from the sides. 
How would I detect such motion using the accelerometer on Windows Phone? This may sound silly, but a solution will be great.

Comment: In theory it's possible. Can you describe why do you need this?

Comment: To pop up or slide respective menus from the top, bottom, sides, when there is a tap detected from the respective side.

Comment: I would be hard to distinguish between tapping and movement. Bad UX.